# How can I create a xaml with comments area along with overlay in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a `NewsFeeds.xaml` in my app. I have tried below xaml and this not looking as expected. On click on the `+` button on top right hand side, system should display an overlay with Title field, NewsComments textarea, save and cancel button.After saving the news, it should display the news from database as per the below screen shot.
Below is my `xaml` code. I have added the overlay part, but how can add the comments section in xaml.

// Updates.xaml added for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="soccerapp.Updates" BackgroundColor="#aa49e3" Title="Updates">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation
        x:Name="popupOverlay">
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Label HeightRequest="50" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Updates" />
            <Button x:Name="plusButton"
              Image ="pls.PNG"
              Width="50" 
              Height="50"
              VerticalOptions="Top"
              HorizontalOptions="Right"
              Clicked="OnPlusButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

// Updates.xaml.cs code

```
namespace soccerapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Updates : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public Updates()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async void OnPlusButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupOverlay.IsVisible = true;
            //EnteredStatus.Focus();
            await DisplayAlert("Updates", "Display Some alert", "Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it would help if you posted a rendering of the actual XAML with notes about the specific discrepancies you want to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried using [Rg.Plugins.Popup for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)?**

Rg.Plugins.Popup - is a cross platform plugin for Xamarin.Forms which allows to open Xamarin.Forms pages as a popup that can be shared across iOS, Android and UWP.

[image: Rg.Plugins.Popup]

You can see sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <Label
            Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

### Sample App here

https://github.com/jesulink2514/PopupSample/tree/master

[image: sample]

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage

Comment: I haven't tried that  plugin yet. After adding the news, I would like to display the `Title, textcontent, date`. How can I add those in my xaml ?

Comment: You can build your dialog in a custom page using `PopupPage` instead of `ContentPage`, and then you can reference in your `MainPage`.

Comment: Now its failing and giving an error...
`The type name 'Animation' does not exist in the type 'PopupPage'
1`

Comment: I have installed the Rg.Plugin as suggested, also I have updated/added my question with  `Updates.xaml` and `Updates.xaml.cs` for reference.

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using? I'll replicate your project.

Comment: Xamarin 16.0.0.513, Xamarin Designer 4.17.4.368, Xamarin templates, 16.0.356

Comment: @soccerway you can review the code (I've updated the answer).

Comment: Still failing though.... `The type name 'Animation' does not exist in the type 'PopupPage'
1>Done building project "soccerapp.csproj" -- FAILED.`

Comment: First, you should remove x:Name="popupOverlay".

Comment: And, if you found another compilation error I recommend deleting bin and obj folders in all projects. I did it and it works.